# Docker Wordpress plugins persistence or mapping to local plugins

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-volume

I am running the latest Docker mac app and have created a new `docker-compose.yml` in my project directory. (which is my wordpress theme).

[image]

This is my configuration `docker-compose.yml` file below...

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  wordpress:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.25.0.0/16

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql:delegated
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wordpress

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/testing:delegated
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_AUTH_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_SECURE_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_NONCE_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_SECURE_AUTH_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_NONCE_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_DEBUG: 1
    networks:
      - wordpress
```

So far i'm finding it awesome. I had a few issues with getting the database to be persistent, and figuring out that `wp-content` folder needs the owner to be set to `www-data`.

But after fixing the above, it's working so good and if I `docker-compose down` and `up` my database is persistent. Plus my database is being pulled from my local theme.

What lets it down is that my plugins folder resets itself if I `docker-compose down` or 
`docker-compose rm`.

Is there some way I could map a local folder from my mac or project theme folder? Then I can store my plugins here so when I `docker-compose up -d` it remembers my plugins.

Any ideas would be awesome.

For example I could put the plugins folder in my local theme folder project...

[image]

---

**SOLVED!**

Because I'm running local dev, npm, composer etc. My aim is to keep a real simple folder structure so my theme is the route of my project in phpStorm.

I've now included my plugins and uploads folder for local persistent data in my theme route project folder by adding following volume mapping (see code below).

This is not your classic Wordpress structure, but I'm not committing `plugins` and `uploads` to version control or my staging server environment. These are purely here for my local persistent data incase I `docker-compose down`.

See my phpStorm project structure now...

[image]

See my `docker-compose.yml` config file...

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  wordpress:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.25.0.0/16

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql:delegated
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wordpress

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/testing:delegated
      - ./plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins
      - ./uploads:/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_AUTH_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_SECURE_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_NONCE_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_SECURE_AUTH_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_NONCE_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_DEBUG: 1
    networks:
      - wordpress
```

Thanks [@Ludi Sistemaš](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11703041/ludi-sistema%C5%A1) for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. You firstly need to rearrange directorys structure.
On your host machine, your using themes directory for mount point. Lets say your going to do it like this. 
Make new directory on your host machine, and call it wp-content. Now you can edit just this line in your docker-compose file which needs to be moved inside of this wp-content directory.

```
   volumes:
       - .:/var/www/html/wp-content/
```

Put your theme in wp-content/themes. 
It should be exactly as if it where on server.
Note: All the other wp default directory structure would be recreated on that mount point, and it will be persistent.

Edit:
 After chatting a bit, I understood what OP needed.
 In order to mount another dir from this architecture. You will need to point to the right path and mount it like this:

```
volumes:
  - .:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/testing:delegated
  - ./plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins
```

Comment: I would like to keep the plugins folder inside project folder as shown rather rearranging the structure again. I'm already storing my database in the db folder here and I don't necessary need version control, I can just exclude this folder from git i just need persistent plugins and potentially the same with uploads.

Comment: Ok, then you can do somethign like this.  ./../plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins and just add it bellow themes in the same manner.

Comment: OK cool let me see if i work it out, I've only just started using docker. Just so I understand is `./../plugins:` this is my plugins folder in project and this mapping it to `var/www/html/wp-content/plugins` ?

Comment: My theme volume map is set to this `- .:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/testing:delegated` so should it be `./plugins:` rather than `./../plugins:` ?

Comment: Docker is sooooo good. Thank you so much that is perfect. My version - `./plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins` and `- ./uploads:/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads` and i'll just exclude these from my version control. I'll update my question above.

Comment: I can also edit my answer so maybe in the future people will find it useful. Im glad I could help you.

Comment: Just updated my answer, see how it's working in project now and the volume code I used. If you remove `/..` from the plugin volume line in your answer I'll except your answer :-)

Comment: Yap, I haven't noticed the change :) . I'm editing right now :)

Comment: Thanks again! Loving docker!